# Is there a unique ID for each Windows User?

Tags: security, hardware

I wasn't sure exactly how to phrase the question. It's about the following:

I have written a program for which you can register to use it for free for 2 days. Now in the past users had often simply created new accounts and this again and again to not have to buy the program.

I would like to counteract this now by collecting and comparing users Hardware IDs in my Database (with permission of the users).
As an example: the graphics card id.

This also works, but unfortunately most of these Ids are not unique. For example, Some Users have the same ID as they both have the same Graphics Card.

Is there any ID that is unique for each user that they won't be able to change that easy using a program that I can use for this?
(If possible not MachineGUID from the registry because some users already know this and change it).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to gather more informations from the users like MAC address, motherboard id, BIOS, ...) when a user create a free account on your software, you collect this informations then check them if the user try to re-create account with this informations